# Strip off metadata from video file on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, video, metadata

I'm developing an iPhone app and need to do something with video files.
I would like to strip off any metadata, then merge the number of video into one video.
Then add metadata to the new video.

I'm considering using `NSData` to read video and merge all `NSData` into one, but don't know how to strip off metadata once its load in the `NSData`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply merge videos together by appending them using NSData containers. Every video contains a header (or footer for some formats). This header tells you how long the video is, where the video starts in the data and what type of compression is used etc. If you want to merge videos, the least you should do is edit that information, but usually it's not that easy. You will probably need to get the uncompressed video data for every video, and then merge them and recompress.
I't not as easy as you may think. However, I DO think the iOS API's can help you get this done.